# html tables, whats the purpose of th

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

What is the reason were having the `th` (X)HTML tag. My thought is that `th` is redundant as it goes under `thead` and `td` should be sufficient.

And if there is a good reason for having `th`, as there probably is, why does not exist a `tf` tag to be placed under `tfoot`?

Comment: th is not just used in the thead. You can use it in the tbody, for instance, as a _row_ header. (i.e. if the leftmost column contains names for the data in the rest of the table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have table heading cells that are not part of a table header. Examples include a *column* of headings and headings that apply to only a section of a (complex) table (the sort where the td elements would need to make use of the `headers` attribute).

Headings are not data so a table data cell would not be appropriate. Footers are for data such as totals, which are still data so `<td>` would be suitable for them.

Comment: True, but I've seen many a table where the tfoot has the very same content as the thead!

Answer (score 1):

`thead` was introduced in HTML 4.0, `th` was older than that (see [HTML 3.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#table)) - so `th` was the only available mechanism for distinguishing the headers from the regular cells. Also, you can use `th` as row headers as well, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Cells in a table may contain two types of information: *header information and data*.

```
The TH element defines a cell that contains header information.
The TD element defines a cell that contains data.
```

This difference enables browsers to render header and data cells distinctly, **even in the absence of style sheets.** For example, some browsers may present header cell text with a bold font.